# How should I handle TCP sockets on a P2P connection software?

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, p2p

I'm starting a new P2P private software. TCP sockets should be used, no UDP. And don't worry about NAT.

As I'm new developing this type of software and networks I have some questions. This software should be able to: add friends, chat with friends and download files from friends, multisource included.

My questions are:

-communication protocol: should I use serialized objects? or maybe Json? I think Json is lighter and fast.

-How should I handle p2p connections and sockets for communication, chat and file transfers? I intend to split files in chuncks for sharing like all p2p software does. But, how should I handle sockets? I mean just one socket for one friend? or maybe a socket for a friend to chat and then one more socket per file downloading/uploading? should I use just one socket for all?

-how p2p software knows the order of downloading that file chuncks?

BTW, I'm using Java because is fast and easier to develop.

---

QUESTION:

how should I handle sockets? Just one socket for one friend for all actions or maybe a socket for a friend to chat and then one more socket per file downloading/uploading?

Comment: This question is too broad as well as opinionated. There are many ways to do this all and SO is not the platform to tutor you trough that. Please read [ask] and feel free to ask questions on specific problems with your implementation.

Comment: Main question is question 2, the rest are details in case people asked.

Comment: Again, it is opinionated. I can tell you how *I* would do it but that doesn't mean it works for you. And other users may have different views on that matter. What you for sure *cannot* do is use one socket for all connections. TCP is "1:1". I recommend using a different channel for upload/download because it may otherwise interfere with chat. Then I wouldn't use serialized objects but a data abstraction in form of XML or JSON or the like. Maybe later on you want to add JavaScript or C#/.net or Python (...) clients ... serialized java objects will then be a showstopper.

Answer (score 0):

The concept of sockets is shared in reference to a server settings, every client as a socket id, when that client attempts a connection with the server that server registers the resulting to its pool of connections.Your environment needs to be multi-threaded to handle concurrent requests from client.Please read the oracle guide.very useful in understanding the concept brought across in a more coherent manner.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/

Comment: I know all that. Doesnt answer my questions about the number of sockets I should use per client for chat or file sharing or any question.

Comment: you only need one socket for every client, you will one central socket, which is master socket. Then child sockets which are incoming connections.